# Wait for page redirect to evaluate `expect()` statement

Tags: angularjs, protractor

So, I'm trying to script a login form for automation through protractor, but running into some problems when I'm trying to verify the cookies after the page redirect.

Here's my sample code:

```
describe('login', function () {
    var app;

    var LoginPage = require('./login.page.e2e.js');

    // Before each test, refresh page
    beforeEach(function () {
        LoginPage.get();

        app = element(by.css('body'));
    });


    // Check route, make sure it hasn't been redirected somewhere strange
    it('should be at path: /login', function () {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/login');
    });


    /**
     * Login as a provider (phoenix.e2e.login.test@leadingreach.com)
     */
    it('should be able to login', function () {

        // Fill out fields
        LoginPage.populate_provider_form();

        // Login as provider
        // Clicking this button fires off an AJAX request that logs in the user, and populates a few browser cookies
        element(by.css('#provider-login-form-container #login_btn')).click();

        // These two statements work fine. They seem to wait for the redirect and end up passing.
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/dashboard');
        expect(app.evaluate('currentUser.username')).toEqual('phoenixe2elogin');

        // The following statements are executed before the page redirects, and therefore fail
        expect(!!browser.manage().getCookies().lrrt).toBe(true);
        expect(!!browser.manage().getCookies().lrco).toBe(true);
        expect(browser.manage().getCookies().lrrm).toBe('false');

    });
});
```

It's been about 3 or 4 months since I created my first Protractor tests, so I'm re-learning all the new syntax, etc.  I'm currently under the impression that using `waitsFor` and methods like that aren't really encouraged (or supported) anymore, so I'm wondering how someone could go about scripting something like this.

Comment: Now protractor handles sync for you, and when sync doesn't depend on angular, you can get protractor instance with `var ptor = protractor.getInstance()` and set `prot.ignoreSynchronization` to true

Comment: So after i set `ptor.ignoreSynchronization` to true, I can use waitsFor? Or what's the syntax for waiting now?  If you have a link to any good protractor docs I'd love to get my hands on them (been trying to search through their GitHub, with not a ton of luck)

Comment: See my answer below for the syntax. Just updated.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get protractor to wait for the element to appear, you have to use the following syntax:

```
ptor.findElement(by.id('my-elt')).then(function (elt) {
    expect(elt.evaluate('my.binding')).toBe('someValue');
});
```

Took me a while to figure this out, hope it ends up helping someone :D